# How to force the admin-ajax.php file to load over HTTPS?

Tags: ajax, redirect, ssl, https

I have a site that I've recently put 100% behind HTTPS. All assets on the front end and the back end are successfully being called over HTTPS, except admin-ajax.php.

This is causing any functionality that depends on the file to fail, including but not limited to CF7, Elementor and other Forms that use AJAX submission, etc.

The error I get, which you can see in the screenshot is "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://toursoft.co/contact-us/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://toursoft.co/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

here is what I've done so far to try to solve the issue.

1) Try everything at https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL including define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true). Even though these are loading the wp-admin/admin-ajax.php file, this is happening from the front end.

2) Added the following to my apache config:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

3) use wp-cli to do a complete search and replace

```
sudo -u www-data wp search-replace 'http://toursoft.co' 'https://toursoft.co' --network
```

This replaced 151 items, even in the GUID column, which is highly advised against by Wordpress. But it did not work. 0 instances of http:// remain in the database

4) Verified that site_url and home options correctly point to https://

Investigating the javascript code that causes the error shows that the code seems to be correctly calling 'ajaxUrl' variable. This variable should hold the https:// version of the file, right?

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    url: t.getSettings("ajaxUrl"), 
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: t.getFormData(),
                    processData: !1,
                    contentType: !1,
                    success: t.onSuccess,
                    error: t.onError
                })
```

The `ajaxUrl` variable is only returning the http version of the script. How else can I investigate this and ultimately fix it so that it loads over https?

[image: mixed content error]

Comment: You sure you converted every reference over to http? `var woocommerce_params = {"ajax_url":"http:\/\/toursoft.co\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","wc_ajax_url":"\/?wc-ajax=%%endpoint%%"};
`

Comment: Same with elementor, something somewhere still has `http` as the site URL

Comment: @TomJNowell Are you saying that these plugins could have the http versions hardcoded into their code? If so can I override that to request the https version via .htaccess / apache conf or through a functions.php filter?

Comment: no because WooCommerce is in use elsewhere without this issue, your attempt to switch to https appears incomplete, traces of non SSL URLs remain. E.g. you might still have `http://` in your main site option or elsewhere, it's not enough to set a config option in the `wp-config.php` file and search replace the posts table

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for the advice so far. I've updated the post to better detail the steps I've taken. I've eradicated every possible occurrence of http:// that I know how to. Suggestions on how to investigate deeper?

Comment: Elementor has it's own search and replace function, use that and then also use Better Search Replace to make sure there's no http references you missed in the db.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Domain Mapping plugin doing this will quickly achieve exactly what you are asking for.

1. Go to: YOURDOMAIN/wp-admin/tools.php?page=domainmapping
2. Under: Excluded pages, check: Force SSL for all pages.
3. Save and you're done.

Your insecure mixed content error due to admin-ajax.php loading via http instead of via https should be gone after this.